# How to know when Recaptcha window is closed

Tags: recaptcha

I'm facing the following situation: When an user clicks a submit button, the app disables the button. Then, when the callback function of the ReCaptcha is called, I can enable the button again. But if the user closes the verify window how can I know that and then enable my button again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was facing the same problem using invisible recaptcha. The way I solve it is `observing` when the captcha was getting closed.

First get the `div` Element containing the captcha.

```
let iframe = document.querySelector('iframe[src^="https://www.google.com/recaptcha"][src*="bframe"]');
let container = iframe.parentNode.parentNode;
```

Then

```
let observer = new MutationObserver( mutations => {
  if(container && container.style.visibility === 'hidden'){
     // Re enable the button 
  }
});

observer.observe(container, { attributes : true, attributeFilter : ['style'] });
```